# Apply regex conditions after certain character

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that i want to parse into an array.
The given string has the form `P[AB, AC, AD] (A1, A2, A3)`.
I want to store it in an array like this so that all the data after the first `(` will be filtered by the regex conditions:

```
P[AB, AC, AD]  
A1  
A2  
A3
```

This is what i came up with:

```
String regex = "/^(([,()]+)$";  
String[] numbers = stringIn.split(regex);
```

My problem is that it simply does not work because the regex won't filter out the pieces, everything is stored at `numbers[0]`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you mean that the values in the '( )' should me filtered by the values in the '[]'?

Comment: If the regular expression doesn't match the string, `String.split(String)` will simply return an array of one component containing the original string. That is what is happening in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying for:

```
String regex = "[ ,()]+(?=[^\\]]*$)";

String stringIn = "P[AB, AC, AD] (A1, A2, A3)";
String[] numbers = stringIn.split(regex);
for (String n : numbers)
{
  System.out.println(n);
}
```

output:

```
P[AB, AC, AD]
A1
A2
A3
```

`[ ,()]+` part tries match spaces, commas and parentheses wherever they appear, but `(?=[^\\]]*$)` (a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) filters out any match before the `]`.  I'm assuming there's only the one set of square brackets in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parenthesis that you want to match literally, and you don't need back-slashes around the body, and you probably want to match instead of splitting.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(stringIn);
if (m.find()) {
  String[] numbers = m.group(1).split("[,\\s]+");
}
```

Finally, unlike in JavaScript and C# and Python, `$` in Java does not match the end of the input.  You need to use `\\z` instead.  `$` in Java matches at the end of input or just before the last linebreak if there is a linebreak at the end of the input.

Comment: No, that’s not quite right. Java works like Perl and Ruby: `$` is the forgiving sort of end of line and `\Z` is the forgiving sort of end of string, whereas `\z` is the unforgiving end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Thought of a less elegant, but possibly easier to follow, way of doing this:

```
// Split the string into two parts.
// parts[0] == "P[AB, AC, AD]"
// parts[1] == "A1, A2, A3"
String[] parts = stringIn.split(" *\\(|\\)");
// Split the second part into its components.
String[] secondParts = stringInParts[1].split(", *");
// Combine the results.
String[] numbers = new String[secondParts.length + 1];
numbers[0] = parts[0];
System.arrayCopy(secondParts, 0, numbers, 1, secondParts.length);
```